# wordpress taxonomy in regular posts

Tags: php, taxonomy

I have a custom post type and taxonomy so the user can post in a specific areas in the theme. User (admin) can add categories easily. But the categories that has been added through my taxonomy don't show up in wordpress regular posts category option.

I do not have any problem with displaying those posts on theme. My problem is to showing those custom categories in regular post's category option.

Is there a way to make ;

a custom category created by taxonomy to be shown in **wordpress regular post's category section**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setting the `$object_type`, the second argument in the `register_taxonomy` function, set the value to an array including your custom post type slug and `post`.

```
register_taxonomy($taxonomy, array('post','your-custom-post-type-slug'), $args);
```

Review: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Also check out my plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/reed-write/. It makes custom post types and custom taxonomies a breeze.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried the code you have given but still the same. I can not see the custom category of taxonomy on wordpress regular post's category section